# Retrieving current versions of an uploaded file in amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3

can anybody tell me the GET url of latest version of uploaded file in amazon s3,
there is no proper GET url in below [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectVersions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the page you linked states:

> A simple GET request retrieves the current version of an object.

Just `GET` the object at its normal url and S3 will always return the current (latest) version.

You only need `?versionId=...` when you *don't* want `GET` to give you the latest version.

---

To learn the version-id of the latest/current version of an object, you would send an HTTP `HEAD` request using the object's key (path).  Like `GET`, if you send a `HEAD` request without specifying a version id in the query string, you get the latest version.  The version id of the object will appear in the HTTP response header `x-amz-version-id`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html

Comment: hey @michael actually i need a current version of the particular object so that i can compare the saved version and latest version, and depending upon that i can hit the URL of the object, as i dont want the user should download the object everytime.

Comment: Updated with additional info.

Comment: still, i havent understood, can you please provide me the url of current version of a particular object, i will provide you the below 2 url which contains the versioning...https://s3.amazonaws.com/testing_testing/billi.jpg?versionId=ZgT9eKI3S.4F4jNq9rJdGMNSp0UCLA9q
https://s3.amazonaws.com/testing_testing/billi.jpg?versionId=3xgL.3vJxZc0xl_348gGqEzTEBlVKjph

Comment: Remove the `?` and everything after.  That is always the url to the current version.  In this case, https://s3.amazonaws.com/testing_testing/billi.jpg is the url to the current version.

Comment: but sir i want the latest version id of that image, before i hit this https://s3.amazonaws.com/testing_testing/billi.jpg

Comment: Send an HTTP HEAD request to https://s3.amazonaws.com/testing_testing/billi.jpg and you will find the version id of the current (latest) version in the `x-amz-version-id` header of the reaponse S3 returns.

Comment: i think u haven't understood my query. All i just want the latest version only, not an whole image, i just need a url and in that url i need to pass the parameter like in this case "billi.jpg" and the output should be the latest version(not the image content i.e raw data).please let me know, if you haven't understood my query?

Comment: I understand your question perfectly.  You want to retrieve the version id of the current version of an object.  Not the object, just the version id of the current version.  To do this, as I have already explained, **you use the URL of the object itself, but you do not send a `GET` request, you send a `HEAD` request.**  `HEAD` does not return the object, it only returns the metadata, and among them is `x-amz-version-id` -- the information you are looking for.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods if you are unfamiliar with `HEAD` requests.